# Where is All in One SEO Pack sitemap.xml located?

Tags: sitemap

I used the XML Sitemaps in the All in One SEO Pack plugin to generate my sitemap.

When I type in the site address/sitemap.xml (http://flysuas.ie/sitemap.xml) the sitemap appears.

I want to get rid of some links that don't make sense but when I look for sitemap.xml on the machine it is not present.

```
sudo find -name sitemap\*
```

Does anyone know where the sitemap is and how it is being assembled to appear as if it is in the htdocs folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sitemap added by most of the plugins (such as Google sitemaps or YOAST SEO pack) is a virtual file added to your websites by the plugin. This file doesn't physically exist, therefore modifying it is not an option for you.

There might be 2 things that you can do about it,

Either find the `php` file that is generating the XML and modify it, or maybe add a filter if it's supported. In your case, the file is located in `/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/inc/sitemap-xsl.php`.

OR

Find the option to demote your URL from the XML list. This option may not exist on every plugin.

Answer (score 1):

hm.. isn't you suppose to run find command in other way?

```
sudo find / -iname sitemap*
```

note for / <- that stands for root directory.

P.S.
Isn't there easier just to check web root of your website for this file?